# Every rational number between $0$ and $1$ is between $1/(n+1)$ and $1/n$ for some $n$

Tags: proof-verification, rational-numbers

Let $a/b$ be a fraction in lowest terms with $0<a/b<1$. Prove that there exists $n∈\mathbb N$ such that $$\frac{1}{n+1}\le\frac{a}{b}<\frac{1}{n}$$

My proof:

If $n∈\mathbb N$
then $n<n+1$ 
and thus $$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}$$
then if we take $n=b$
it follows that $$\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{b+1}<\frac{1}{b}\le\frac{a}{b}$$
so we have shown that $$\frac{1}{n+1}\le\frac{a}{b}$$

Comment: It's not at all clear how you conclude "thus, if..."  It's clear that $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}$, but how do you know there is such an $n$? In particular, you've never used $a/b$ anywhere in that argument...

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for part a is rather flawed:  After doing a few correct manipulations, you go from the valid statement that $\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$ to simply stating that which you were to have proven.

The sort of thing you would need to do is first show that there exists some $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} < a/b$ (hint: choose $n=b$), then assume there is no $n$ satisfying $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq a/b < \frac{1}{n}$ and show on that basis by induction that $a/b \geq 1$.  Having demonstrated that contradiction, you will have proven the theorem.

Comment: Thanks! How does it look now? I understood your explanation up until the assumption point

Comment: @MathMajor For $a/b = 5/6$, you have produced the fraction $1/6$.  Does this satisfy $1/7 \leq 5/6 \leq 1/6$?